# Wordpress plugin to SAVE post-publish edits, without actually PUBLISHING those edits

Tags: version-control, wordpress

I am working on a CMS using wordpress 3.3.1. With my previous question, in this respect I got a couple of plugins through which I can elevate the rules for my users. For example now my contributor can

1. Make a new post
2. Edit already published posts

What I cannot achieve is to attain the **Publish Mode** which is the sole authority of the administrator.

1. When the contributor edits a publish post, the edits take place on the live site.
2. If the contributor saves the post as drafts, the original post is deleted from the live site.

I am looking for some sort of **version control** to achieve my goal. The contributor edits an already published post which is saved in the DB as a new version. The administrator approves this new post and the old version on the live site is replaced by the edited one.

Any help or plugin info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a lot of RnD and can conclude that **Revisionary** along with **Role Scoper** can be used for the exact purpose.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress already saves versions as its going on a regular basis in-case your computer crashes, perhaps you can have a save button for this?

Comment: well that's not exactly I want. I want my user to edit his/her post and the new edit is saved into the database as a new **unpublished** version.